# How to add the drop down for IAM role in cloudformartion script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cloudformation

I want to add a dropdown for an existing IAM roles while creating a stack. The Parameter Type - AWS::IAM::Role gives only a text box to put the IAM role.I already have a role defined to create a stack and launch an instance. But how do I show the roles in the dropdown?

The snippets given in the documentation refer to the IAM policy creation and root user access.

Any suggestions for IAM Role drop down?

Comment: Are you referring to IAM Role attached to instance in AWS::EC2::Instance (IamInstanceProfile property) ?

Comment: No, I am not referring to the role attached to the instance. The cloud formation service will check whether the selected role has the permissions or not. If the selected role is not permitted for the stack operations the auto-rollback will be performed. I want all roles in the dropdown that are defined in my account.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. CloudFOrmation supports only the following AWS-Specific Parameter Types: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types